# Accessing method parameters from asynchronously running lambda

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda

What I know: only `final` or effectively `final` local variables are accessible from inside a lambda. `static` variables are also accessible and can be modified as well.

What I do not know: why this code does not throw an exception?

```
public static String sampleFunction(String param1, int param2) {
    new Thread(() -> { 
        try { Thread.sleep(100000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        // accessing method parameter here...
        String _param1 = param1;
        System.out.println(_param1);
    }).start();

   return "";
}

public static void Main(String[] arguments) {
    sampleFunction("to print", 9);
    System.out.println("function returned");
}
```

So having that in mind the parameters are released on return
which happens before trying to access them from inside the asynchronously running `lambda` expression, why does not it throw `Exception`? I tested the code, compiled and interestingly the "returned" message was printed earlier than "to print".
Which means that I could access the method parameters after the method returned.

Comment: which exception do you expect?

Comment: I have no idea. I just find it weird I can still access the method parameters even after the method returned. Maybe a NullPointerException?

Comment: of course, the parameter `param1` is not accessible from the lambda. The lambda is like an object, and it keeps value of `param1` inside.

Comment: Interestingly the lambda can access the method parameter even after the method’s return. It executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would not throw an Exception as param1 is effectively final. Java Lambdas are similar to closures.